# Can I prevent a specific datamember from being deserialized?

Tags: wcf, serialization, datacontract, datamember

I have a datacontract like this

```
[DataContract]
class MyDC 
{
    [DataMember]
    public string DM1;

    [DataMember]
    public string DM2;

    [DataMember]
    public string DM3;
}
```

and *sometimes* I want to prevent DM2 from being deserialized when being returned from an OperationContract. Something like this:

```
[OperationContact]
public MyDC GetMyDC()
{
    MyDC mdc = new MyDC();

    if (condition)
    {
        // Code to prevent DM2 from being deserialized  
    }

    return mdc;
}
```

I could always make a new DataContract that has only DM1 and DM3 and generate that from the MyDC instance but I want to see if it is possible to programatically remove DM2. Is it  possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[DataContract]
class MyDC 
{
    [DataMember]
    public string DM1;

    public string DM2;

    public bool IsDM2Serializable;

    [DataMember(Name="DM2", EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string DM2SerializedConditionally
    {
        get
        {
            if(IsDM2Serializable)
                return null;
            return DM2;
        }
        set { DM2=value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string DM3;
}
```

Then set IsDM2Serializable to false when you need to hide it:

```
[OperationContact]
public MyDC GetMyDC()
{
    MyDC mdc = new MyDC();

    if (condition)
    {
        // Code to prevent DM2 from being serialized  
        mdc.IsDM2Serializable = false;
    }

    return mdc;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this is to set the EmitDefaultValue property of the DataMemberAttribute to false:

```
[DataContract]
class MyDC 
{
    [DataMember]
    public string DM1;

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string DM2;

    [DataMember]
    public string DM3;
}
```

Then setting this property to null:

```
[OperationContact]
public MyDC GetMyDC()
{
    MyDC mdc = new MyDC();

    if (condition)
    {
        // Code to prevent DM2 from being deserialized  
        mdc.DM2 = null;
    }

    return mdc;
}
```

This way, that property doesn't get written to the output stream on serialization.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347792.aspx

Comment: That works if I am creating a copy of the actual object I want to serialize, and don't care about changing the copy. However, I would like to do it without changing the object I am trying to serialize.

Answer (score 3):

What you mean is serialization and not deserialization.

If you prepare a class for serialization applying the `[DataContract]` attribute to the class, only the members of the class that has `[DataMember]` attribute will be serialized:

```
[DataContract]
class MyDC 
{
    [DataMember]
    public string DM1;

    public string DM2;

    [DataMember]
    public string DM3;
}
```

In some more complex cases the usage of `[IgnoreDataMember]` can solve your problem. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx)

By the way, you can serialize fields and properties, regardless of accessibility: `private`, `protected`, `internal`, `protected internal`, or `public`. You can serialize any read/write properties and not only fields. About serialization of collection types see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can prevent an attribute from serialization. 
Put `[DataContract]` Annotation on class and `[DataMember]` for only serialized attribute. if you want to skip attribute when that attribute value is null then put `[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]` on that attribute.

Example:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass 
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id{ get; set; } 
    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string MessageBody { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public DateTime SentOn { get; set; } 
}
```

Note: SentOn will be serialized when **it is not null** and others will be serialized in every condition.